# Why does eth0 have no IP after reboot? Running dhclient -v fixes

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, dhcp

When I reboot my Raspberry Pi, my WiFi connection works, but my eth0 interface has no ip adresss.  In the gui it says "eth0: Link is up, configuring"

If I run `dhclient -v` it will obtain an IP and the interface works.

I do not added any customization to `/etc/network/interfaces` nor have I configured anything additional in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`

It appears to me that it's just not trying to obtain an IP on that interface on boot up.

Running Raspbian stretch (version 9).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know `eth0` doesn't have an ip addr? Enter `ip link show eth0` from the command line, & tell us what you see. Then enter `sudo ip addr show eth0` & share that here.

Comment: `dhclient` is not used. By default `dhcpcd` is used on Raspbian. The wifi connection works. Where is the wired port **eth0** connected to? Is it another router than that for the wifi?

Comment: @ingo: Good catch! Can you provide a reference for RPi using `dhcpcd` instead of `dhclient`? I know it's true (I actually never heard of `dhclient` until I read this question), but after a search, I couldn't find any document that stated `dhcpcd` was used, and `dhclient` was only vestigal.

Comment: @Seamus [Another Raspbian Desktop User Interface Update](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-raspbian-desktop-user-interface-update/), posted 8th May 2015 at 9:45 am, first section **New Wifi Interface**: "*Connecting to a wifi network has been made much simpler in most cases by including a version of Roy Marples’ excellent dhcpcd and dhcpcd-ui packages.*"

Comment: @Ingo: Apparently the [decision to adopt `dhcpcd` was not universally admired :)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=140045)... in fact, some think it was a bad decision. I've learned a few other things from reading various [posts re `dhcpcd` on The Organization's website.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dhcpcd+site%3Araspberrypi.org&ia=web). It all suggests (to me) that a) adopting `dhcpcd` *may* have been a dodgy decision, and b) `dhcpcd` is not as solid as I have thought for a while?

Comment: @fehays: Could you please let us know what version hardware you have?

Comment: @Seamus I know the discussion about *dhcpcd* and I also not happy with it. The foundation has missed a chance to look forward. You know that I prefer systemd-networkd. But this off topic now ...

Comment: @Seamus I was just running `ifconfig eth0` to see that there was no ip address assigned. I have a pi 3B.  See my answer below on what fixed it.  Unfortunately I'm not sure who the culprit was.  Maybe you smarter folks will have an idea.  Thanks!

Comment: Would you be willing to spend some time doing more detailed logging of `dhcpcd`, and sharing the results?

Answer (score 1):

`dhclient` and `dhcpcd` are different DHCP clients. Using both in a mixed mode is not a good idea and may give you the problems. `isc-dhcp-client (dhclient)` is not installed by default so you should deinstall it and only use `dhcpcd`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why, but the `dhcpcd` service status was reporting that it was trying to obtain an IP address already assigned to a different MAC address on my network (was one of my TVs).  I checked my router config and didn't have an IP reservation set up for that address.  I was able to fix it, but I'm not sure if it was my router that is the problem or something else.

I ended up using `dhclient` to get an IP address.  Then went in to my router config and reserved that IP for my pi.  Then rebooted the PI and `dhcpcd` auto obtained the reserved IP as expected.

Comment: Using two dhcp clients, `dhclient` and `dhcpcd`, at the same time is a misconfiguration. I cannot suggest any other user to follow this "solution".